# Blur Select2 input after close

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want the select2 element to lose the focus when the select2-close event is triggered, what I have tried so far was:

```
.on("select2-close", function (e) {
    var $focused = $(':focus');
    $focused.blur();
});
```

and some variations to get focused element like `document.activeElement`, $(e.target) non f these worked.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Lcy/)

Comment: please view my comment at link https://stackoverflow.com/a/46251972/2134005

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to remove the `.select2-container-active` class from the containing divider:

```
.on("select2-close", function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.select2-container-active').removeClass('select2-container-active');
        $(':focus').blur();
    }, 1);
});
```

I've used a `setTimeout` here as a hacky way to ensure that this triggers after the plugin itself finalises the close.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/Q6Lcy/3/).

Comment: Are you sure that your code removed the focus from the select2 element? Just try to log the focused element after your call. Really simple test.

Comment: @akoskm ah sorry, I'd removed your part of the code. I've added `$(':focus').blur();` back in and updated the JSFiddle.

Comment: Okay, I realized that your fiddle is different from your answer and without `setTimeout` it won't work. Please edit your answer and I'll accept it. The 'setTimeout' is crucial in this case.

Comment: @akoskm ah sorry, I'd forgotten about that too! Slow morning...!

Comment: This select2 Github issue may be related - ["Blur event fires at the wrong time with newer versions of jQuery"](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/1545)

Comment: whats the containing divider?