# Focusing Input after Select2 close event fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I read [always trigger "change"-event for <select>, even if the select2-option clicked is already selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486281/always-trigger-change-event-for-select-even-if-the-select2-option-clicked-i/24372411) and as the problem was so close to my issue I asked my question there but no answer provided. My problem is that I have a select-box constructed by Select2 and a text input. What I want to achieve is after **Select2 closed** (no matter the value is changed or not) my text input become **focus**.

So I did something logically fine as follow:

```
$('#select').select2({placeholder: 'City'});
$('#select')
.on('select2-close', function (e) {
   $('#hey').focus();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sobhanattar/x49F2/8/

As you can see, the text input doesn't accept focus. After some digging in Select2 document and inspecting Events part of documentation, I realized that after Close event, there is a Focus event fire automatically. It means that after you close a Select2 select-Box, it focuses itself. So I changed my code to something like this:

```
$('#select').select2({placeholder: 'City'});
$('#select')
.on('select2-close', function (e) {
       $('#select').blur();
})
.on('select2-blur', function(e) {
      $('#hey').focus();
});
```

And it works just fine. Now I want to know that my understanding from Select2 order of events was correct or I missed something in the middle.

Answer (score 6):

take a look here, this question is already has an answer:
[Blur select2 input after close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157181/blur-select2-input-after-close)

```
.on("select2-close", function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.select2-container-active').removeClass('select2-container-active');
        $(':focus').blur();
        $("#elementid").focus();
    }, 1);
});
```

`elementid` is the id element you want to be focused after select2 closese.
i have just added `$("#elementid").focus();` to the answer at link.

Comment: In the newer versions of Select2 the event name is now select2:close  (colon instead of dash).

Answer (score 5):

Try this one as it works:

```
$('#select2').on('select2:close', function (e)
{
   // your focus code for element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use css:

```
html, body {
    height:100%
}
```