# Keep the focus after selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm often using select2 in my applications and contrary to [Blur Select2 input after close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157181) I'm looking for a way to keep the focus after selection.

As we can see in the [official examples](https://select2.github.io/examples.html), blurring the input seems to be the default behavior after the selection (unlike the regular select).

This behavior is quite annoying when filling a form with the keyboard because <kbd>tab</kbd> won't go to the next input.

**Is there a simple way to keep the focus in the input after selecting a value ?**
*A way that can be configured globally*

Comment: Are you try `.on("select2-close", function() {
    var select2Data = $(this).data("select2");
        select2Data.search.blur();
  });`?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem with the [select2 token/tag-inputs](https://select2.org/tagging) and was able to solve it by listening for the `select2-close`-event and then finding the search-input and give it the focus after a short delay/timeout.

```
.on('select2:close', function (e) {
    var select2SearchField = $(this).parent().find('.select2-search__field');
    var setfocus = setTimeout(function() {
        select2SearchField.focus();
    }, 100);
});
```